# ?? Operator with 2 strings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In this .NET code:

```
return Redirect("~/Home" ?? "JaneDoe");
```

If I'm reading the docs right, the "[`??`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)" operator appears to operate similarly to IsNull in SQL:

```
IsNull("~/Home", "JaneDoe")
```

`"~Home"` and `"JaneDoe"` are simply strings, right? There's no condition in the `return Redirect` code where "JaneDoe" will be what's passed into "Redirect", is there? I'm not sure what to make of this snippet, I can only presume it's a placeholder for something to come later.

This code is from a .NET-MVC project in development, part of a `.cs` file that is a LoginController.

Comment: You should submit this to TheDailyWTF.com

Comment: I think you mean IfNull, not IsNull.

Comment: I'm thinking of this IsNull -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms184325.aspx

Comment: @siride No, the proper SQL command is ISNULL(whatToCheck, replacementIfNull).  NULLIF(x,y) (not ifNull) is actually a very different SQL command, as it returns (x==y)?null:x;

Comment: IfNull, not NullIf.  Looks like MS SQL doesn't have it.  MySQL and some other DBs have it.

Comment: @siride it's also similar to COALESCE() (MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce T-SQL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms190349.aspx )... though that takes an arbitrary number of parameters rather than just 2.

Comment: Yeah, I know about COALESCE, but I was just "correcting" the simple case.

Comment: @siride You are correct.  NullIf is TSQL shortcut for coalesce(x,y) and IsNull is msSql shortcut for coalesce(x,y).  I'm not sure if either or neither is in ANSI SQL.

Comment: http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt seems to indicate `NULLIF` and `COALESCE` are ANSI Standard.

Comment: @ARM Drink more coffee.  IsNull is TSQL shortcut for COALESCE(x,y) and IfNull is mySql shortcut for COALESCE(x,y).  NullIf is ANSI (implimented in TSQL/mySql) and does return (x==y)?null:x; as I stated in my first comment... not a coalesce shortcut.

Comment: "IsNull is TSQL shortcut for COALESCE(x,y) and IfNull is mySql shortcut for COALESCE(x,y)" I love these pseudo-shortcut shenanigans.

Comment: @martinho Well there are some important differences between the two.  First of all, COALESCE(x,y,z,r,q) can take N number of options while ISNULL(x,y) can only take two.  The other big, and important, difference is COALESCE is nullable while ISNULL is not.  I just wish either ISNULL or IFNULL would become part of the ANSI standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is just bad code. That will *always* be equivalent to

```
return Redirect("~/Home");
```

I'm slightly surprised the compiler isn't smart enough to give a warning about it, to be honest. It would be nice if it could tell that a constant non-null expression was being used on the LHS of the null-coalescing operator.

Comment: @artlung: It looks like whoever wrote the code is still learning too ;)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: :-| Yes, at this point I'm not seeing much of a difference between sample .NET-MVC projects (e.g.: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1 ) and this.

Comment: I know the ReSharper plug-in would have caught this, dunno about the vanilla VS check-as-you-go.

Comment: In order for the compiler to catch it, someone on the compiler team has to think of the scenario first. I would never have expected anyone to pass a *literal string* to the ?? operator.

Comment: That said, the compiler does track which expressions *cannot possibly be null* in order to implement a minor codegen optimization. (An invocation of a non-virtual instance method on an expression that cannot possibly be null can skip the null check on the receiver). We could use this information to check whether the left hand side of the null coalescing operator cannot possibly be null.

Comment: @Dan: Is in beta. I'm not following your train of thought.

Comment: I was wondering if the compile-time check on non-null value coalescing   was going to be in SP1. :)

Comment: @Dan. Nope. We've missed that train.

Answer (score 3):

The [??](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to define a default value for a nullable value types as well as reference types. It returns the left-hand operand if it is not null; otherwise it returns the right operand.

In your case, it will never return JaneDoe

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're reading it correctly. That will always return "~/Home", presumably it was planned to change it to a variable at some point.

Comment: Thanks, yes, it seems to be a placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, the expression will never return "JaneDoe".

Answer (score 1):

This would always use the `"~/Home"` string. The null-coalescing operator (??) selects the left side if it is non-null, or the right side if it is null.